# Cell image resized after row tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I have an odd bug, after use tap row cell's image changed. I didn't implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, so i guess its just table reloading forces image to redraw.

Here is code:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //  Загружаем ячейку из класса, далее подгружаем текст из класса initialData.

    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NewsParseer *news = [self.objectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Text
    cell.textLabel.text = news.text;

    // Image
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:news.urlImage];

    return cell;
}
```

Very simple. Here is screenshots, first - when app launched and load image. Second, when i tap a row.

[image]

[image]

Obviously i don't want image to resize after user interaction.

Comment: r u using auto layout ? try constraining the image view

Comment: @Mr.T yes i use it. Problem is not size of UIImage (it fit almost whole screen), but size of its content.

Comment: is the cell for row at index got called again when u tap ? what are the image properties in both cases ? did u try to NSLog ?

Comment: @Mr.T no, im not, but image size at web server is fixed..

Comment: try to look in the view debugger, what happens to the image view after the image is stretched...Also log the image properties in both cases

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that wondered whats going wrong, there is answer:

I tried to set image to default property of cell, called `imageView`, but in `Storyboard` and in my custom class i work with different image view (property that i call `myImageView`).